How to get a realistic progress value from useProgress in React-Three-Fiber?
I'm building a 3D website using react-three-fiber and @react-three/drei. I want to display a dynamic loading bar that shows the progress of model loading using the useProgress hook from @react-three/drei.
However, I'm facing an issue where the progress value returned by useProgress doesn’t seem accurate or realistic. Here’s a snippet of my code:
import { Html, useProgress } from "@react-three/drei";

const Loader = () => {
  const { progress } = useProgress();

  return (
    <>
      <Html center>
        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex h-screen items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-75">
          <div className="w-full max-w-lg px-4">
            <p className="mb-4 text-center text-white">
              Loading... {Math.round(progress)}%
            </p>
            <Progress value={progress} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Html>
    </>
  );
};

And I'm using Suspense like this:
<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <AsyncModels />
</Suspense>

Is there a better approach to get more realistic progress feedback when loading 3D models in react-three-fiber?
I saw this and tried it, but I still have no idea.
React Three Fiber useProgress Hook Always Returns 0
